# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined in Nexmo API

Tags: node.js, vonage

I am trying send WhatsApp message using Nexmo API, but its throwing exception as send of undefined.

```
const nexmo = new Nexmo({
  apiKey: apiKey,
  apiSecret: apiSecret,
  applicationId: "*************",
  privateKey: "/****/private.key"
})

nexmo.channel.send(
  { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "**********" },
  { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "************" },
  {
    "content": {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "This is a WhatsApp Message sent from the Messages API"
    }
  },
  (err, data) => { 
    if (err) {console.log(err)}
      else
      {
        console.log(data)
      }
   }
);
```

Exception in sending message ...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (*****/trail1.js:14:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

Comment: Are you using the Beta version of `nexmo` package? `npm install nexmo@beta`. See https://developer.nexmo.com/messages/code-snippets/client-library

Comment: It's working fine after Beta version installation, But it showing '''title: 'Your request parameters didn\'t validate.''' as error.